# Merge the [vapor] and [vapor3] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Neither [vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor) nor [vapor3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor3) attracts many questions and the use of the earlier versions of Vapor is falling away.

Questions are being tagged as [vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor) when they are, in fact, using Vapor version 3, so there is some accidental misuse and I have re-tagged a couple of questions. Although there are significant differences between Vapor 2 and Vapor 3, there were similar changes between Vapor 1 and Vapor 2 that did not warrant version-specific tags.

Would it be better to merge the two into just the original [vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor) tag?

Answer (score 3):

There were just 5 questions in the [vapor3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor3) tag which did not have the [vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor) tag (including deleted questions), and it was clearly being used interchangeably as mentioned in the original post. I merged the tags and also I have created a synonym in this direction:

[vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor) × 412   <- [vapor3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor3) × 88

I added another [vapor2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor2) tag as a synonym to [vapor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vapor), just in case someone creates a new tag for Vapor 2 (though, as the original post mentions, the usage is fading, and no one might create a tag)